# Python: Bytes to string giving escape characters

Tags: python, json

rmsg variable is bytes.
Value is:

```
rmsg = [{"Id": "A1", "status": "P", "message": ""},
        {"Id": "A2", "status": "F", "message": ""}]
```

I want to convert it to string so as to pass it to JSON message. I am using below command to convert it to string.

```
rmsg = rmsg.decode("utf-8")
```

Using below command to create JSON:

```
rjson = {"Response Message": rmsg}
```

JSON message=

```
{
    "Response Message": "[{\"Id\": \"A1\", \"status\": \"P\", \"message\": \"\"}, {
\"Id\": \"A2\", \"status\": \"F\", \"message\": \"\"}]\n"
}
```

But Im getting escape character: \n at the end. I dont want to use strip command to remove it.
Any other ways to pass bytes to JSON string without dealing with escape chararcters?

Comment: How are you actually getting `rmsg`? Because `rmsg = [{"Id": "A1", "status": "P", "message": ""},  {"Id": "A2", "status": "F", "message": ""}]` is a `list` of `dict` and not `bytes`.

Comment: @Axe319...Im getting rmsg from subprocess command of python(flask). r = subprocess.run(l, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) and rmsg = r.stdout. When I do print(type(rmsg)) it shows class=bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to keep the JSON as a string, you can do the next:

```py
rmsg = json.dumps(json.loads(rmsg.decode('utf-8'))
```

It will load data from JSON string and then dump it again to a string, but in one line, so no `\n`s etc.

But probably what you really want is to have the JSON stored as a dict/lists. In this case, you can do the next:

```py
rmsg = json.loads(rmsg.decode('utf-8')
rjson = {"Response Message": rmsg)
```

Update: In case the original `rmsg` can contain a valid JSON *or* just a string, you should handle this (through exceptions handling). For example:

```py
rmsg = rmgs.decode('utf-8')

try:
    rmgs = json.loads(rmsg)
except JSONDecodeError:
    pass

# ...
```

Comment: Igor Its working fine for this rmsg. But Its throwing this error for other rmsg which have different format: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). For rmsg = Admin or rmsg = FileInstalled, its throwing error. Im using second method: rmsg = json.loads(rmsg.decode('utf-8')
rjson = {"Response Message": rmsg)

Comment: @Azkaban in case the `rmsg` originally can contain a JSON _or_ just a string — you should handle it (through exceptions, for example).

Comment: @Azkaban I've added an update to my answer.

Comment: Igor after adding exception handling, its working fine for 7 of the 9 rmsg that I have. For 2 its still returning escape char. rmsg= Id Installed !!!
Id Not Installed !!! (both are in different lines). Output: {"Response Message": "Id Installed !!!\nId Not Installed !!!\n"} 
And rmsg= Administrator. Output: {"Response Message": "Administrator\n"}

Comment: @Azkaban then for `except` part you can add something like `rmgs = rmsg.replace('\n', ' ').strip()` instead of `pass`.

Comment: Ya I did that. Thanks Igor